# Scheduled Task on Windows Server 2008 R2: batch keeps running

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I have a batch running every 5 minutes as a Scheduled Task.
The batch code calls another batch: `cmd.exe /c c:\bin\ftp_send.bat` (this does a lot more than ftp).

When this batch was invoked on Windows Server 2003, it ran and stopped when done - usually less than 4 minutes.  On 2008 it does not stop - status on Refresh is always 'Running'.  It finally reads 'Ready' after my configuration in Settings is triggered to 'Stop the task if it runs longer than: 30 minutes'.  Also under Settings, 'If the task is already running...' is set to 'Do not start a new instance'.

If I change the cmd.exe to the 64-bit version `cd c:\%windir%\syswow64` it stops the task when done, but breaks some of the executables called from 'ftp_send.bat'.

If I call it direct with the 64-bit version `c:\%windir%\syswow64\cmd.exe /c c:\bin\ftp_send.bat`, it doesn't break any code, but it does not let the task stop when done.

I don't know what else to try, except maybe to set 'If the task is already running...' to 'Stop the existing instance' or 'Run a new instance in parallel'.
I could set 'Stop the task if it runs longer than: 5 minutes' but I'm afraid it may not complete all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done to debug it (send output to a log file, watch with Process Monitor, etc)? It could be blocking on user input for some reason, or legitimately taking a long time to run.

Comment: syswow64\cmd.exe is the 32-bit version, not the 64-bit version. The 64-bit version sits in system32. (Yes, this is counterintuitive.)

Comment: Thanks. @Bill: I did not know that, and yes - counterintuitive.  The EXEs that are called from ftp_send.bat are 32-bit, so that starts to make sense I guess.  But I wonder why it works when I cd to the location, but not when I include it in the batch line.  Andrew: I noticed 2 instances of cmd.exe running and neither turning off.

Comment: A bit hard to suggest anything when we have no idea what's in your script.

Comment: Well, it was written by unknown parties back in 1997, and is about 6200 lines of code, which call another dozen or so batches and EXEs. :(  Not the easiest to figure out at this end either.  Thanks for the helpful tip.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a redesign of the script, particularly if it's not working on the newer platform the same as it did before.