# Changing ComSpec in Systems Properties doesn't change default cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008-r2

This is related to another post for 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2: 
[Scheduled Task on Windows Server 2008 R2: batch keeps running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530449/scheduled-task-on-windows-server-2008-r2-batch-keeps-running)

I guess I am mistaken, but I thought if I changed the `ComSpec` path for cmd.exe to `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\cmd.exe` by doing so in System Properties - Advanced - Environment Variables, calling cmd.exe in a batch file would invoke the 32-bit version under `\syswow64`.
But when I view the instance of cmd.exe in Task Manager when the batch is running, the Properies still show the path as`\system32`.

Is there another way to achieve a default 32-bit cmd.exe without registry changes?

Comment: You may explicitly call `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\cmd.exe` in your batch file...

Comment: Yes I've done that, thanks.  I was just looking for a quick 32-bit default.

Comment: I need to dig deeper.  When the batch runs, I get 2 instances of cmd.exe - 1 64-bit and 1 32-bit.  I will post what I find when I find it.